# remove x axis labels for ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

giving the following data:

```
    data2 <- list(structure(list(super_group = c(1,1), Group.1 = structure(3:4, .Label = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Pr1 = c(65, 75), Pr2 = c(54, 88), Prh = c(25, 5), SE = c(25, 75 )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), NULL, structure(list(super_group = c(3,3), Group.1 = structure(3:4, .Label = c("A","B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), Pr1 = c(81,4), Pr2 = c(66, 57),Prh = c(3,3), SE = c(8, 9)), row.names = c(NA,
-2L), class = "data.frame"))
```

to plot using ggplot2:

```
 data2 %>%
 bind_rows() %>%
 ggplot(., aes(x = Group.1, y = Pr1, fill = Group.1)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
 facet_grid(. ~ super_group)
```

-you see C and D labels in the x axis which are not necessary. So I want to remove them and reduce the width of the bars.  any ideas?

-can we move  1  and 3 from x axis top  to x axis bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `switch` argument to `facet_grid` to change the position of facet labels.
Arguments `axis.text.x` and `axis.ticks.x` control the text and tick on the x axis. To remove them declare them as `element_blank()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
data2 %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Group.1, y = Pr1, fill = Group.1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ super_group, switch = "x") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) -> p1
```

[image]

To change the proportions of the graph save it with different dimensions. Example:

```
ggsave("p1.pdf", plot = p1, device = "pdf", width = 3, height = 5)
```

Or if using `knitr` change the chunk options by defining:

`fig.width=3, fig.height=5` for example:

````
```{r p1, fig.width=3, fig.height=5}  
data2 %>%
      bind_rows() %>%
      ggplot(., aes(x = Group.1, y = Pr1, fill = Group.1)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      facet_grid(. ~ super_group, switch = "x") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```
````

and to change the width of the bars use argument `width`:

```
data2 %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Group.1, y = Pr1, fill = Group.1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.5) +
  facet_grid(. ~ super_group, switch = "x") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

another option (based on the comments it seems to me this is the desired one) is to change `expand`:

```
data2 %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Group.1, y = Pr1, fill = Group.1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ super_group, switch = "x") +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(1,1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: In fact I meant the width of the bars in the plot not the width of the plot.

Comment: Added another way using `expand`. Check edit please.